# php uploading csv files, reading it and then creating the files

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I am uploading a csv file with this code:

```
$_ferror = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$_fsize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_fpath."/" . $url);
```

where $_fpath contains the path to the directory where I want the files stored and the $url contains the file,name: "$url = $_FILES['file']['name'];"

my question is, how can I open the file, before I move it... I want to read from it and take the data in it, and then create 3 files from the one...

Based upon data I find in it.

Say I want these three files:

currentdate-type1.csv
currentdate-type2.csv
currentdate-type3.csv

Say the csv has these fields:

name,phone,type,email,address1,address2,city,state,zip,country

then I open it, find the "type" and if the type is, say, good, then put that whole line in a file I name currentdate-type1.csv, then if the type is great, put that in currentdate-type2.csv and if the type is awesome I put those lines in currentdate-type3.csv...

I guess, I could have it where the original file is the type1, then I just pull out those for type2 and type3....

Those are just examples, not really what I am wanting to do. I just cannot figure out how to start.

I want to start by reading the file... getting the first line, into an array of all the  field names, so I can check which one is the field I want to get the data from in the data-rows....

Can you tell me how to open that file to read from it, getting the first line... for the fieldnames?

I would really appreciate tips, or where to find that on php training pages.

Thank you so very much in advance for any tips and/or pointing me to where I can learn that specifically how to...

Comment: I edited your question a bit for readability. However, Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: `$f = fopen($_FILES['tmp_name'], 'r' ); $line = fgetcsv( $f );`  However there are some security reasons to use `move_uploaded_file`  - by the way `$_FILE['tmp_name']` is the file, so you can do anything to that you can to a normal file.  PHP don't care about the extension.   http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: so the file is here: $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] or here: $_FILES['tmp_name']? Interesting.

So I just open it and read it like any file? (Sorry I'm pretty new to PHP, I'm mostly a perl guy, but trying to learn PHP better now...)